# Backup and Restore PostgreSQL Database using pg_dump, pg_restore

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Hi every one i am using `postgresql` database for my project which is built in `codeigniter` , now i want to backup and restore my database through `php` by using pg_dump, pg_restore and `psql` , i don't know where to run manually these command so that i can check it manually from command line, i have search many site but all of them are telling about the command, they aren't saying about what to install and how to run the command and also how to run in `php` in windows environment.

Comment: have you tried CI Database utility class for taking backup check CI document for this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#backup

Comment: i have tried it but i dont want to create it utility class as the size of my database is large so it can't handle my problem